# cy.task('auth:seed-users') failed with the following error: > Cypress is not defined

Tags: node.js, cypress

For some reason I cannot access neither `Cypress` nor `cy` inside task body described in a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task body is executed at the `Node` side (as opposed to the browser one for the main test logic) where I assume neither `Cypress` nor `cy` are bound.
But why do you need them?

Comment: Yeah, that's true, indeed I just want to share some data between task and test body. Cannot find any solution for that purpose.

Comment: you can pass any number of arguments into a task. do you need something else?

Comment: The data I generate inside task I want to access from task body as a variable or something.

Comment: task may return a value as well, see here for example: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Save-a-variable-across-non-same-origin-URL-visits

Comment: Ok, it returns a value, which is great, but the value is being generated inside a task, where I cannot access `cy` to store it.

Comment: I've figured out, tasks themselves may return value, thanks!